# my website Product Archives pages show only two products I am using commerce and all setting is ok , how to solve this?

Tags: wordpress, web, woocommerce

screenshot for this problem only shows two products https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6CAf.jpg

Answer (score 0):

how much products you uploaded to this archive? you have to upload more than 5 products to show them in your archive page.

Comment: I have more than **2000** products and there are many pages but each page shows 2 products only

Comment: they all are published? please check the status.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Elementor or something else? If so, take a look at which query you gave.

Or use some shortcode like this:

```
[product_category id="your_category_id" per_page = "12" column = "3" orderby="id" order="DESC"]
```